# Computing square root using Schoof's Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I was reading Schoof's paper where he proved that $x^2=a \bmod p$ can be solved in poly($a,\log p$) time . To do that you construct $E$ such that End(E) =$O_K$ I understand that in order to construct an elliptic curve :

You talk about hilbert class polynomial $H_p(X)$ which is minimal polynomial of the  $j$-invariants of the elliptic curves $E$ for which you have End(E) =$O_K$ . Computing $H_p(X)$ is not much difficult. And now my problem begins . Now it says that find one root $j_0$ of $H_p(X) = 0 \bmod p$ and from that you construct $E$ such that End(E) =$O_K$ and you are done with part 1.

Here is my question : how do you compute $j_0$ from $H_p(X)$  because if we can really do this for any $f(X) \bmod p$ then we might as well simply do this for $f(X) = X^2 -a $ . Also you cant brute force as it will not then be poly in $\log p$ . Something has to be wrong with my understanding or very special for these $H_p(X)$ .

Can anyone please clarify this point that after computing $H_p(X)$ how do you proceed?

PS: Here is the link of schoof's paper (http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777280-6/S0025-5718-1985-0777280-6.pdf) and Chenal's master thesis ( http://algant.eu/documents/theses/chenal.pdf) from which I tried understanding the algorithm. An help or comment will be helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

The running time of the algorithm to compute the square root of $a$ mod $p$ is polynomial in $\log p$ but not in $a$. The Hilbert polynomial that is used does not depend on $p$ as you write, but only on $a$.